# Adding wild card to squid ACL

Tags: linux, squid, access-control-list

I want to add a wild card to squid ACL.

acl mp3_ext url_regex s-i *.mp3

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/acl/) covers these situations...

```
acl mp3_ext url_regex [-i] \.mp3$
```